# Is there a 3D animation tool that meets these requirements?

Tags: 3d, physics, animation, tools

I'm searching a 3D physics / transforms animation editor. It should be able to import 3D meshes from OBJ or FBX, then it should be able to animate transforms. I need such a tool for my 3D games, where many dynamic and inorganic elements appear, like doors, traps, robots, lifts, and so on.

Where I can find such a tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably the case that you're only going to find what you want as part of a larger 3D art production suite.

For example, [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) should be able to do this, as should any other 3D modelling package (such as Max or Maya, although those are non-free and in fact quite expensive).

Blender and the other tools of its class are very powerful and can do all that you need (and much more), but they do have a bit of a learning curve associated with them. Fortunately Blender has a lot of [documentation](http://www.blender.org/download/documentation/) and [tutorials](http://www.blender.org/education-help/tutorials/) available.